# Firefox opens up blank when opened with selenium

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

Using python2.7, selenium (latest version downloadaded with pip) and Firefox 25.0.1 in Windows 7.

I try to run the following minimal example of selenium code but it just opens a blank Firefox page and throws a WebdriverException:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 60, in **init**
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 71, in **init**
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 113, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 164, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 136, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
WebDriverException: Message: u'\r\n\r\nGateway Timeout 504\r\n \r\n\r\n'

I have no conections problems when I run the test script using Selenium IDE, only with python code.
How can I fix this? I cannot advance past the "driver= webdriver.Firefox()" line.

Comment: Do you have a proxy configured, any thing set in your hosts file, or any sort of network sniffer or maybe even firewall/virus scanner running on your machine?  If my memory of how IDE works is correct, IDE is directly plugged in to the browser, but running tests from a driver API actually communicates via localhost networking with a browser plugin, so funky local network conditions on your machine could blow it up.  Looking at your call stack, things are blowing up when the client driver is attempting the initial to connection to the plugin server, so that points to a local networking issue.

Comment: I'm running this from my workplace and has its firewalls and IT policies.

Comment: Maybe the first thing to try is to check your system proxy settings.  There should be a checkbox to ignore proxy settings for local addresses.  Make sure that it is checked.

Comment: I checked the "bypass proxy server for local addresses", and didn't make a difference. I will check the same code this afternoon at home to see if the network makes a difference. Thanks.

Comment: Not the network per se, but the machine's local network settings.  There's a good chance it won't work on that machine, but it should work on a different machine.

Comment: It worked at home, I'll try in different machines here at work. Thanks. Question solved. :-)